# CSS DIV Height 100%

Tags: css, height

I have 3 divs in a wrapper.
one of this divs contains my content `class="cont"` this div has a dynamic height. The other divs navi-left and und navi right should have a hight like div cont. i have tried this but it dont work. can you help me please?

```
<div style="width:400px;">
    <div class="navi-left" style="width:50px; height:100%; background:grey;"></div>
    <div class="cont" style="width:80px; height:80px; background:blue;"></div>
    <div class="navi-right" style="width:50px; height:100%; background:green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: navi-left and navi-right should have 80px too. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a fluid 3 colum layout of equal height, then check [this 'holy grail' post](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm).

In order for a percentage height to trigger, the height of the parent should be known. Also, your DIVs should be displayed inline if you want them to all show on the same row.

```
<div style="width:400px;height:80px;">
    <div class="navi-left" style="width:50px; height:100%; background:grey;"></div>
    <div class="cont" style="width:80px; height:80px; background:blue;"></div>
    <div class="navi-right" style="width:50px; height:100%; background:green;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {display:inline-block;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvepX/

Comment: what can i do if div cont are dynamic ?

Comment: It should re-size to the appropriate length set by cont.